# Some mornings, debian virtual machine pegs the CPU and becomes unresponsive

Tags: linux, kernel

On some mornings, usually between 6:30 and 8:30am, my virtual machine locks up to the point where it causes collateral damage to the VMWare server host itself.  I cannot SSH into the VM nor the host while this is happening.

I believe I've narrowed this down to the mlocate job in cron.daily.  But of course there shouldn't be something *wrong* with that cron job so there's a larger problem at hand that I cannot identify.  For what it's worth this machine has pretty limited amount of RAM, 384MB.  Perhaps not realistically, but this exceeds debian's requirements, and I know that the system isn't doing much else during the time of day that this issue arises.

Here are some things I'm getting in my messages log:

```
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.955528] updatedb.mloc D ddadc12f     0  3274   3270
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.955615]        d746ece0 00000082 0011caef ddadc12f 000221d2 d746ee6c c1309fc0 00000000
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.955692]        d60c3b4c 01142a38 07a53f31 00000000 01142a38 d60c3b4c 01142a38 c6ae3d3c
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.955709]        c1309fc0 00f4f000 c6ae3d3c c1300e28 c02b9048 c6ae3d34 00000000 c0190d2e
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.955723] Call Trace:
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.956038]  [<c02b9048>] io_schedule+0x49/0x80
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.956472]  [<c0190d2e>] sync_buffer+0x30/0x33
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.956511]  [<c02b9236>] __wait_on_bit+0x33/0x58
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.956515]  [<c0190cfe>] sync_buffer+0x0/0x33
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.956524]  [<c0190cfe>] sync_buffer+0x0/0x33
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.956527]  [<c02b92ba>] out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x5f/0x67
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.956533]  [<c0131a91>] wake_bit_function+0x0/0x3c
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.956583]  [<c0190cca>] __wait_on_buffer+0x16/0x18
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.956593]  [<d89b153d>] ext3_find_entry+0x37a/0x515 [ext3]
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.957163]  [<c01bae24>] security_inode_alloc+0x16/0x17
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.957192]  [<c0184900>] alloc_inode+0x12e/0x186
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.957210]  [<c0184ce9>] iget_locked+0x5b/0x100
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.957217]  [<d89b2bea>] ext3_lookup+0x21/0x9b [ext3]
Jul 18 08:30:02 core kernel: [607607.957228]  [<c017aac3>] do_lookup+0xb6/0x153
Jul 18 08:30:13 core kernel: [607607.957233]  [<c017c6c4>] __link_path_walk+0x726/0xb26
Jul 18 08:30:13 core kernel: [607607.957239]  [<c0186f4c>] mntput_no_expire+0x13/0xd9
Jul 18 08:30:13 core kernel: [607607.957243]  [<c017cafb>] path_walk+0x37/0x70
Jul 18 08:30:13 core kernel: [607607.957247]  [<c017cdaa>] do_path_lookup+0x122/0x184
Jul 18 08:30:13 core kernel: [607607.957251]  [<c017d607>] __user_walk_fd+0x29/0x3a
Jul 18 08:30:13 core kernel: [607607.957255]  [<c0177625>] vfs_lstat_fd+0x12/0x39
Jul 18 08:30:13 core kernel: [607607.957276]  [<c01776b9>] sys_lstat64+0xf/0x23
Jul 18 08:30:13 core kernel: [607607.957283]  [<c0103857>] sysenter_past_esp+0x78/0xb1
Jul 18 08:30:13 core kernel: [607607.957344]  =======================
```

And slightly less recently,

```
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.377450] ionice        D 299741d5     0 32588  32441
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.377515]        ce11a5e0 00000086 02a1416f 299741d5 000755a5 ce11a76c c1209fc0 00000000
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.377578]        c38d5f6c 058eebe6 003d2086 00000000 058eebe6 c38d5f6c 058eebe6 c3b9fd08
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.377598]        c1209fc0 00e4f000 c3b9fd08 c12001cc c02b9048 c3b9fd00 00000000 c0190d2e
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.377612] Call Trace:
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.378275]  [<c02b9048>] io_schedule+0x49/0x80
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.379280]  [<c0190d2e>] sync_buffer+0x30/0x33
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.379325]  [<c02b9236>] __wait_on_bit+0x33/0x58
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.379331]  [<c0190cfe>] sync_buffer+0x0/0x33
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.379338]  [<c0190cfe>] sync_buffer+0x0/0x33
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.379342]  [<c02b92ba>] out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x5f/0x67
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.379348]  [<c0131a91>] wake_bit_function+0x0/0x3c
Jun 30 07:44:11 core kernel: [2065298.379399]  [<c0190cca>] __wait_on_buffer+0x16/0x18
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379415]  [<d09af08d>] ext3_bread+0x44/0x5b [ext3]
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379680]  [<d09b0f50>] dx_probe+0x3a/0x2ad [ext3]
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379692]  [<c01e046c>] rb_insert_color+0x4c/0xad
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379741]  [<d09b1280>] ext3_find_entry+0xbd/0x515 [ext3]
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379753]  [<c01344ec>] hrtimer_start+0xf7/0x110
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379760]  [<c01361e0>] getnstimeofday+0x37/0xbc
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379765]  [<c0134658>] ktime_get_ts+0x22/0x49
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379769]  [<c0155174>] delayacct_end+0x70/0x77
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379788]  [<c0156aee>] sync_page+0x0/0x36
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379803]  [<c0155249>] __delayacct_blkio_end+0x56/0x59
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379810]  [<c02b9063>] io_schedule+0x64/0x80
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379816]  [<d09b2bea>] ext3_lookup+0x21/0x9b [ext3]
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379827]  [<c017aac3>] do_lookup+0xb6/0x153
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379847]  [<c017c6c4>] __link_path_walk+0x726/0xb26
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379852]  [<c0131a49>] __wake_up_bit+0x29/0x2e
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379857]  [<c01621a6>] __do_fault+0x30e/0x34d
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379863]  [<c017cafb>] path_walk+0x37/0x70
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379867]  [<c017cdaa>] do_path_lookup+0x122/0x184
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379872]  [<c017d78c>] __path_lookup_intent_open+0x42/0x72
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379878]  [<c017d80b>] path_lookup_open+0xf/0x13
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379882]  [<c0177c98>] open_exec+0x1d/0x94
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379900]  [<c0164be3>] free_pgtables+0x86/0x93
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379906]  [<c0182b46>] dput+0x25/0xbb
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379912]  [<c0178d13>] do_execve+0x48/0x1c6
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379917]  [<c010213b>] sys_execve+0x2a/0x4a
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379944]  [<c0103857>] sysenter_past_esp+0x78/0xb1
Jun 30 07:44:12 core kernel: [2065298.379984]  =======================
```

I'll point out that ionice is in fact used by the mlocate cron job.

**Edit:**
This problem seems sporadic--it totally kills the machine maybe once a week, but it also appears to get worse with uptime.  I really don't want to blame the cron jobs because I typically run debian lenny on almost all of the servers I install and support--there's nothing unusual here.  Could it be a memory leak?  I say it gets "worse" with uptime because I'm running nagios on my vmware host, and usually after 4-6 days I start getting load warnings in the morning for a minute, then two minutes the next day.   I've been trying to remote in while it's happening, but I just cannot connect to the guest VM while it's happening to see what else is going on.

Comment: Have you tried manually running the cronjob to see if it causes the problem you are having?  Do you have any network filesystems mounted?  You may want to make sure mlocate is excluding them.

Comment: disable all non-critical cron-jobs - if you have nothing critical, disable all cron jobs - to see if that fixes it, if it does then do the individual testing of each job

Comment: I tried running the updatedb.mlocate command manually--it was absolutely no problem.  I think this corresponds with another problem.  Also if I wipe out the mlocate database and run updatedb again, it only takes a couple minutes and not 2+ hours, as implied by cron.conf and the system messages.

There are no external or remote storage volumes.

Comment: If you can't connect in to see what is going on, you may want to setup a cron job that appends the output of ps to a file every 10 minutes or so.  If you haven't installed it, then install sar/atsar this tool will gather, normally every 5 minutes.  These stats would let you collect data over several hours and days.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe mlocate is the symptom, but not the cause. Do you have any other cron jobs on the server? Try to remove them (if they are not *really* necessary) except mlocate and see if it happens again. Do you have any mounted filesystems on the server?

Comment: I absolutely agree that mlocate is not the cause.  Here's the thing, I commented out the entirety of /etc/crontab and this is still happening at 6:30 every morning.  This leaves me to suspect the host vmware server's cron jobs.  So today I commented out its crontab as well and we'll see what happens.

But again, there's nothing unusual about my set up here AFAICT, and I've been running vmware server atop debian for many years.